# Ensure converging to 0, not -1, with binary string

Tags: java, binary, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

I'm using cooperative coevolution to solve a couple of function optimisation problems, and am having issues.

The functions take N parameters, where each parameter is a number, and all the functions minimise when each and every one of the N parameters is 0.

My representation of the 'individuals' for use in cooperative coevolution is a binary string, so I can perform bit-flip mutations (it's imperative I keep this representation).

Due to the fact that the functions converge when the parameters are zero, of course -1 is pretty close. However, in 32-bit binary representation, -1 is a string of 32 1s, where 0 is a string of 32 0s. I such get stuck in a local optimum, where some of the parameters are -1 and others are 0.

So my question is, how does one go about avoiding/getting out of this? Is it acceptable to probabilistically flip all 32 bits with a probability equal to that of my mutation rate?

Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using machine internal representation is considered harmful because it leads to **deceptive solutions** in genetic algorithms.

There are many articles about **MDP** (Minimal Deceptive Problem) in genetic algoritms that cover this topic, for example:
http://www.dtic.mil/get-tr-doc/pdf?AD=ADA294072

and great David Goldberg's book which explains deceptive problems and MDP and **Building Blocks hypothesis** (*Genetic Algorithms in Search, Optimization, and Machine Learning, David Goldberg*).

Internal representation of **signed integer** is **Two's complement** which leads to deceptive chromosome encoding where:

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111   = -1 
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000   =  0
```

If you want to use this **Two's complement** encoding, then I suggest to **mask most left bit** to make individual always positive number and then convert to float number with any offset you want.

For example:

```
int a = ...   // any value from 0 to 0x7fffffff
float x = ( ((float) a) / 0x7fffffff ) * 100 - 50.0;

// now x is in range: -50.0 .. 50.0
```